# Objective-C class property in category causes warning

Tags: objective-c, xcode8, class-properties

In Xcode 8.3.2 and Objective-C, if you have a class property in a category, it sometimes causes a warning. How can I get rid of it?

The warning is

```
ld: warning: Some object files have incompatible Objective-C category
definitions. Some category metadata may be lost. All files containing
Objective-C categories should be built using the same compiler.
```

The class property would look something like this:

```c
 @interface NSObject (Thingie)

 @property (class, readonly, strong) id thingie;

 @end
```

And the implementation

```c
@implementation NSObject (Thingie)

+ (id)thingie {
  return nil; // doesn't matter for this
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you switching between xcode8 and xcode9 Beta?

Comment: @Sulthan Nope. FWIW, I'm trying to create a minimal app that repros the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue. It happens when you use a newer version of Xcode (not sure what the version cutoff is) and your project defines an Objective-C category that declares one or more class properties and you also link to a library that was built with a version of Xcode that didn't support class properties.

I was able to eliminate the warning by translating my class properties into "getter' methods.

In your case, update your .h file to:

```
@interface NSObject (Thingie)

+ (id)thingie;

@end
```

That covers the `class` and `readonly` attributes of the property. And the `strong` attribute is essentially superfluous in a read-only property.

This conversion has no effect on the usage. You can still do:

```
id aThingie = someObject.thingie;
```

Comment: It could be different now, but previously code completion didn't work for dot-notation for these kinda-properties.

Comment: Cool, glad they fixed it.